# Cannot move file to subdirectory of itself

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm having a little problem with renaming a bunch of files in a folder.
The script:

```
for file in $1 
do
    mv $file $file | sed -r 's/^.{20}//' | sed 's/.\{16\}$//'
done
```

The output:

```
mv: cannot move `/home/timothy/Videos/DB/' to a subdirectory of itself, `/home/timothy/Videos/DB/DB'
```

The SED command is correct, it's just that I'm doing something wrong with the mv parameters.

These are the names of the first 5 files:

```
[a-s]_dragon_ball_-_001_-_the_secret_of_the_dragon_balls__rs2_[4FC1375C]
[a-s]_dragon_ball_-_002_-_the_emperors_quest__rs2_[59F9C743]
[a-s]_dragon_ball_-_003_-_the_nimbus_cloud_of_roshi__rs2_[0C592F5F]
[a-s]_dragon_ball_-_004_-_oolong_the_terrible__rs2_[47CE4923]
[a-s]_dragon_ball_-_005_-_yamcha_the_desert_bandit__rs2_[B6A035BF]
```

And it should become this:

```
001_-_the_secret_of_the_dragon_balls
002_-_the_emperors_quest
003_-_the_nimbus_cloud_of_roshi
004_-_oolong_the_terrible
005_-_yamcha_the_desert_bandit
```

Comment: Can you give an example what is your file name and to what you want to rename?

Comment: @souravc 
original: [a-s]_dragon_ball_-_001_-_the_secret_of_the_dragon_balls__rs2_[4FC1375C]

New: 001_-_the_secret_of_the_dragon_balls

Comment: Since you are piping, the `sed` commands only receive the the stdout of the `mv` command which is pretty boring (normally emtpy when not called in verbose mode). So what is executed first is the `mv` command which tries to rename a file/directory into itself. This is not allowed. What you probably want to do is pipe the second `$file` through the `sed` commands and use the result as the target filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you have files like,

```
[a-s]_dragon_ball_-_001_-_the_secret_of_the_dragon_balls__rs2_[4FC1375C]
[a-s]_dragon_ball_-_002_-_the_emperors_quest__rs2_[59F9C743]
[a-s]_dragon_ball_-_003_-_the_nimbus_cloud_of_roshi__rs2_[0C592F5F]
[a-s]_dragon_ball_-_004_-_oolong_the_terrible__rs2_[47CE4923]
[a-s]_dragon_ball_-_005_-_yamcha_the_desert_bandit__rs2_[B6A035BF]
```

these files have [a-s] at beginning. And you want them after rename as, (according to your comment)

```
001_-_the_secret_of_the_dragon_balls
002_-_the_emperors_quest
003_-_the_nimbus_cloud_of_roshi
004_-_oolong_the_terrible
005_-_yamcha_the_desert_bandit
```

Use this script below,

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in [\[a\-s\]]*
do
    newfile=`echo "$file" | sed -r "s/^.{20}//" | awk -F "__rs2" '{print $1}'`
    mv $file $newfile
done
```

**How it work**

This script scans all filenames in current directory that starts with "[a-s]". Next inside for loop for every scanned file name the script creates new file name leaving first 20 characters filtered through`sed` and cuts part starting with string "__rs2" . That removes unwanted parts in the name. And lastly the files are renamed to new file name one by one.

**Usage**

Save the code as `rename_file.sh`.(say) Next put it at the same directory where all these files are. Give the script execution permission. Write in terminal,

```
chmod +x rename_file.sh
```

Finally to rename the files, just write in terminal,

```
./rename_file.sh
```

Done.

Comment: Good exhaustive answer!

Comment: Nice answer! Sadly I get following error: mv: cannot stat `[a-s]*[4FC1375C]': No such file or directory 

I will edit my inital problem with more info

Comment: I edited it again. try it now. I think it is here what you want.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanx a lot

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you

```
#! /bin/bash
for file in "$1"
do
    target_name=$(echo "$file" | sed -r 's/^.{20}//' | sed 's/.\{16\}$//')
    mv "$file" "$target_name"
done
```

Comment: The weird thing is: my folder DB just disappears

Comment: How do you call the script? And what's the file/directory structure?

Comment: I cd to the correct directory (Desktop) and give following command in commandline: ./rename.sh /home/timothy/Videos/DB/ It's an mkv file which is located in /home/timothy/Videos/DB/

Comment: OK. So one other problem was that your script was designed to work on files but you were passing a directory to it. Well, I guess @souravc being familiar with these type of files has offered a good solution to the problem.